# How to combine multiple mysql results in php

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to combine the results of a mysql query into a single result after the request. The reason is the request depends on several nested if statments. As I attempt below, Id like to take all the results with name X item Y and make them a single result adding the duration, and displaying the date as a range.

```
if($_POST['comp']==2){
     $sum=0;
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
         foreach($row['EMP'] as $name){
             foreach($row['ITEM'] as $item){
                 $duration=(($row['T_OUT']-$row['T_IN'])/60)/60;
                 $sum += $duration;
                 $stamp=$row['STAMP'];
                 $datetime = explode(" ",$stamp);
                 $date = $datetime[0];
                 echo "<fieldset>Log: " .$row['LOG']. " Date: " .$datetime[0]. " <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"timeact[]\" value=\"TIMEACT\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"date[]\" value=\"".$datetime[0]."\">Name:<input name=\"EMP[]\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $name. "\">Job:<input name=\"ITEM[]\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $item. "\">Duration:<input name=\"time[]\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $sum. "\">Notes:<input name=\"NOTE[]\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $row['NOTE']. "\"></fieldset>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Are you getting an error? What is the behaviour of the code you ahve given and the expected behaviour.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea It displays nothing. It should combine all results where Name(EMP) and Activity(Item) converge with a single result. This result should have the cumulative hours for each Activity(ITEM).

Comment: a) you don't show your SQL - have you verified the query outside of PHP?; b) to debug, place a basic echo for each value and comment out all the 'math' - once you're getting all the values you can create the code to develop the final, required output. Good luck.

Comment: @user3741598 the query works fine on other `if($_POST['comp'])` options. Thank you :)